# Is there a way in python3 to check for more than one thing?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, python-3.x

Like, for example:

```
pie = 1
if pie == 1 OR 2:
  print("pie is either 1 or 2!")
else:
  print("pie is not 1 or 2!")
```

Except you know, something that actually has the intended effect. Because that doesn't work. :P

Comment: Following your rule, if I wrote `if pie == 1 or pie == 2` the compiler would interpret this as `if pie == 1 or pie == (pie == 2)`. This would be confusing. Also, for this case, if pie is always an integer, you can write `if 1 <= pie <= 2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if pie == 1 or pie == 2
...
if pie in (1, 2)
...
```

Comment: For the second syntax, using a tuple would be better since you are not going to change it. Not that it is going to make any difference in this case at least, but that is the better convention :)

Comment: This should be a tuple! Python constructs literal tuples something like five times faster than literal lists.

Comment: @aaronsterling @sukhbir Indeed. Just came from my code, where there were a list. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @aaronsterling: The correct story is that recent Pythons construct literal tuples at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Same way as in 2.x.

```
if pie in (1, 2):
   ...
```